# Trying to scan a list of names into a double pointer

Tags: c, string, scanf

I have no idea what is wrong here. Trying to scan a list of names: 
bob
tim 
tony
alison
jim

etc. into double pointer **strings but I keep getting a seg fault dont see where.

```
void insert_data(char **strings, const char *filename, int size)
{
    int j = 0;
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
            printf("File could not be opened");
            return;
    }

    for(j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
            fscanf(file,"%s", strings[j]);
            printf("%s\n", strings[j]);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

I have a separate function to allocate memory but it still seg faults

```
void allocate(char ***strings, int size)
{
    strings = malloc(size * sizeof(char*));
    if(strings == NULL)
    {
            printf("Could not allocate memory\n");
    }

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
            *(strings+i) = malloc(MAX_STRING_LEN * sizeof(char));
            if(strings == NULL)
            {
                printf("Could not allocate memory\n");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: The trouble is likely in the code that calls this.  There are minor issues here, such as not testing the result of `fscanf()` — you should be checking that it returns 1 and exiting the loop if not — but on the whole it is reasonable code.  Note that you need to pass an array of pointers, not a pointer to a 2D array, to make this work.

Comment: your `allocate` function wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The core of your function is more or less sound; the problem is more likely in the way you invoke it than in the function itself.  The following code, which has only minor fixes to the code in the function, works OK.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int insert_data(char **strings, const char *filename, int size)
{
    int j = 0;
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "File %s could not be opened\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        if (fscanf(file, "%s", strings[j]) != 1)
            return j;
        printf("%s\n", strings[j]);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return size;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char data[10][20];
    char *str[10];
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        str[i] = data[i];
    int n = insert_data(str, argv[1], 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d: [%s] [%s]\n", i, str[i], data[i]);

    // Invalid - incompatible pointer type!
    // int m = insert_data(data, "data2", 10);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that given the function prototype, you must pass an array of pointers, rather than trying to pass a pointer to a 2D array of characters.  The compiler warns if you try to misuse the function.

Comment: Would someone care to explain their down-vote?  Presumably not.  Damn Anonymous Cowards!

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
#define _S(x) #x
#define S(x) _S(x)

void insert_data(char **strings, const char *filename, int size)
{
    int j = 0;
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
            printf("File could not be opened");
            return;
    }

    for(j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
            fscanf(file, "%" S(MAX_STRING_LEN) "s", strings[j]);//E.G. #define MAX_STRING_len 64
            printf("%s\n", strings[j]);
    }
    fclose(file);
}

void allocate(char ***strings, int size)
{
    *strings = malloc(size * sizeof(char*));
    if(*strings == NULL)
    {
            printf("Could not allocate memory\n");
            return ;
    }

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
            (*strings)[i] = malloc((MAX_STRING_LEN+1) * sizeof(char));
            if((*strings)[i] == NULL)
            {
                printf("Could not allocate memory\n");
                return ;
            }
    }
}
```